# Event Log Monitoring from salesforce API

Tags: webservices, rest, event, workbench, eventlogfile

Below is my requirement:
I have to track the event(eg: URI event) from event log file without manually using workbench or REST explorer.
It means I have to write a code where it queries the URI event from log file and gives me an output with csv formatted logfile. Here manually I should not use workbench to hit the webservice.everything should be automated in my code and I get the output with daily running batch job(example).

Please do suggest me an idea of how to overcome this.

Thanks In Advance
Sravika

Comment: Best if you could enumerate some ideas you have tried or are considering

Comment: It is like I have to download the event log file from my apex code itself. For example: I want to get URI event type information from my apex code.

Comment: see also: http://www.cloudlock.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/CloudLock-Product-Sheet-Salesforce.pdf and http://www.fairwarning.com/cloud-security for vendor solutions

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about this mechanism [Using Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) then in general you will need to use some technology other than Salesforce/Apex to do the work e.g. one of the [stacks available on Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/features). You will need to write code that makes the REST web service calls, parses the data and constructs the CSV output.

The problem is that the event monitoring data volumes are large and so it is easy to exceed the 6MB/12MB (for synchronous/asynchronous code) Apex heap limit as streaming IO is not supported. So using Apex - you can make [REST calls from Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm) - only makes sense if you are sure that the data returned by the API calls you need to use plus the output you want to generate all fit within the relatively small heap limits.